# How do I add a remember login details button to my website?

Tags: reactjs

I've looked around for an answer to this for a few hours now and not really found anything, I thought it would be easy as basically every site has it. All I want to know  is how do websites safely store your username and password so that the next time you load your browser and go to sign in, the username and password input fields are already filled in?

I've read about localStorage, but a lot of people seem to say that's not safe. I'm using react in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Browsers have that feature already.

Answer (score 0):

You may store JWT in a persistent cookie or [browser local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to create this functionality.

freecodecamp does a good job explaining this step by step:

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-persist-a-logged-in-user-in-react/

You could even persist your state in a statemanager such as redux and rehydrate your store based on new incoming data.